# Loop on html objects and obtain a single array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have some html objects like:

```
<input id="myfield1" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield2" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield3" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield4" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield5" class="fields_to_iterate">
```

and if I do in javascript:

```
$('.fields_to_iterate').each( (index, element) => { 
    myObject.push( { [$(element).attr('id')] : $(element).val() } ); 
});
```

On console.log debug get as result an object like this:

```
transferBook: Array(7)
0 : {myfield1: 'value1'}
1 : {myfield2: 'value2'}
2 : {myfield3: 'value3'}
3 : {myfield4: 'value4'}
4 : {myfield5: 'value5'}
length: 5
[[Prototype]] : Array(0)
```

but I'd like to get only one array like:

```
transferBook: Array(1)
0 : {myfield1: 'value1', myfield2: 'value2', myfield3: 'value3', myfield4: 'value4', myfield5: 'value5'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]] : Array(0)
```

How I could modify my .each() to push in single array? Thanks to all! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who needs jQuery?

```js
const myObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(".fields_to_iterate"),
    ({ id, value }) => [id, value]
  )
);

console.log(myObject);
```

```html
<input id="myfield1" class="fields_to_iterate" value="one">
<input id="myfield2" class="fields_to_iterate" value="two">
<input id="myfield3" class="fields_to_iterate" value="three">
<input id="myfield4" class="fields_to_iterate" value="four">
<input id="myfield5" class="fields_to_iterate" value="five">
```

See

- [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

---

If you really want it in an array, simply wrap it in square brackets

```js
const myObject = [Object.fromEntries(...)];
```

Comment: I liked that solution but I had also to push so I could obtain myObject = [{...}] in this way I can iterate inside in php to save in db , thanks @Phil !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) of key value pairs for each input's `id` and `value`.

```js
const myObject = {}

$('.fields_to_iterate').each((index, element) => {
  const id = $(element).attr('id')
  const val = $(element).val()
  myObject[id] = val
});

console.log(myObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myfield1" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value1">
<input id="myfield2" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value2">
<input id="myfield3" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value3">
<input id="myfield4" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value4">
<input id="myfield5" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value5">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need solution based on JQuery Use `reduce` instead `each` like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="myfield1" value="x1" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield2" value="x4" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield3" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield4" class="fields_to_iterate">
<input id="myfield5" class="fields_to_iterate">
<script>
    const myObject = $('.fields_to_iterate').get().reduce((acc, el) => {
        const obj = {};
        obj[$(el).attr('id')] = $(el).val();
        return { ...acc, ...obj };
    }, []);
    console.log(myObject);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `map` instead, and `Object.fromEntries` to create an object from an array of key-value pairs.

```js
let res = [Object.fromEntries($('.fields_to_iterate').map((i, el) => [[el.id, el.value]]).get())];
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myfield1" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value1">
<input id="myfield2" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value2">
<input id="myfield3" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value3">
<input id="myfield4" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value4">
<input id="myfield5" class="fields_to_iterate" value="value5">
```